# Validating an input which i know just part of its name in laravel

Tags: laravel, validation

I have a form with dynamic inputs which are like: min_1,$min_2,...$min_1000,$max_1000, I want to validate these elements to be numeric and to be required. As i am not sure about the name of inputs to be validated, how can i write the role. I need some thing like 
$min_(what ever): required|numeric
I appreciate any help. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
foreach($request->all() as $item)
{
     $rule[$item] => "required|string"
}

Validator::make($request->all(),$rule);
```

Let me know If you get any errors.

Don't forget to mark it answer if works

Hope it helps you

Thank you